# composer --version no response crashed

Tags: composer-php

On mac pro:

1. With this command:

   curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

I get no response.

2. I only get it from:

   https://getcomposer.org/download/

And following instructions:

```
sudo mv pwd/composer.phar  /usr/local/bin
```

=> composer  has been in the folder(./bin)

But in a terminal:

```
composer --version     
composer --help
```

No response and no error

Any idea?

Comment: Improved question legibility.

Comment: try to move file like this: `sudo mv pwd/composer.phar  /usr/local/bin/composer`

Answer (score 0):

Follow this instruction https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-macos. Also check that file `/usr/local/bin/composer` has permission `execute` by `ls -la /usr/local/bin/` if not then use `sudo chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/composer`